# Setting default value for optional argument that depends on another optional argument in python argparse

Tags: python, default, argparse

I am using python `argparse()` for command line parsing. I want something like this,

`-a` -> optional argument

`-b` -> optional argument that depends on `a` with `default value x`

**Condition**: `-b` should set(either to `default` or custom value) if and only if `a` is set, otherwise `b` should be `None`.

Could someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: This best done after parsing.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. Cant we do before parsing? Do we have any params in add_argument() for this?

Comment: There is a `default` parameter, which you can set anytime before parsing.  But trying to change the default during parsing is a lot more work than doing a few simple tests after.

Answer (score 2):

`@hpaulj`'s comment still holds. This is best done in code after parsing

But you could do it with the `@property` and your own `MyNamespace` object instead of default argparse namespace

The @property lets you write arbitrary code for getters/setters of a particular class object (in this case b)

```
import argparse 

class MyNamespace(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self._b = None   # this is a variable to store the actual value of 'b'

    @property
    def b(self):
        if self.a:
            return "DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_B_SINCE_A_IS_SET"
        else:
            return self._b or None
    @b.setter
    def b(self, input):
        self._b = input

def parse():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-a")
    parser.add_argument("-b")

    out = parser.parse_args(namespace=MyNamespace())
    print("A =", out.a)
    print("B =", out.b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse()
```

##### When both a, b are passed (in any order)

```
$>python testparse.py -a xyz -b pqr
A = xyz
B = DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_B_SINCE_A_IS_SET

$>python testparse.py -b pqr -a xyz
A = xyz
B = DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_B_SINCE_A_IS_SET
```

##### When only b is passed

```
$>python testparse.py -b pqr
A = None
B = pqr
```

##### When only a is passed

```
$>python testparse.py -a xyz
A = xyz
B = DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_B_SINCE_A_IS_SET
```

##### When none of them is passed

```
$>python testparse.py
A = None
B = None
```